# Property 'x' does not exist on type 'MakeMatchers'

Tags: typescript, expect, playwright, playwright-test

I'm a newcomer to Typescript and am struggling to see why I get this error:

[image]

At the top of the file I import `expect` from Playwright:
`import {expect} from "@playwright/test";`

This function as shown comes from `interface PageAssertions{ //` within the `@playwright/test` declaration file `test.d.ts`.  However, I seem to be able to use any assertion that is in `expect-types.d.ts with no error.

I have tried installing following as both dev and standard dependency in my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1",
```

I don't have `expect` being imported anywhere else (i.e. from Jest).

I see this in node-modules:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to reproduce that, not even by overcomplicating it a little bit.
I created a file called `title-checker.ts`

```
import { expect, Page } from "@playwright/test";

export class TitleChecker {
    constructor(readonly page: Page){}

    checkTitle(title: string) {
        expect(this.page).toHaveTitle(title);
    }
}
```

And then I have this test:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { TitleChecker } from './title-checker';

test('wait', async ({ context, page }) => {
  await page.goto("https://www.mabl.com");
  await page.locator('"Login"').click();
  new TitleChecker(page).checkTitle('login | mabl');
});
```

Everything worked as expected.

Comment: weird. Thanks for checking.

Comment: @Steerpike Did you find an answer to your question?